# Which language has better Bitcoin API experience, C# or Node.js?

Tags: c#, bitcoinjs, node.js, nbitcoin

At the moment it seems to me on the .NET side NBitcoin would compete with Bitcoin.js on the other.

Update: I decided on NBitcoin. It has a [great book](https://github.com/ProgrammingBlockchain/ProgrammingBlockchain) to learn from.
Note I will not form opinion on my question, I contributed a great chunk of this book, so I would be biased.

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of service you are building? Exchange, market place? Raw Bitcoin transactions? From the experience, Python has really really strong Bitcoin support. In any case node.js and Bitcore from Bitpay is one of the most high quality libraries available https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore

Comment: I'm working at a payment processor company and we are about to set up a crypto division. Based on the experience of my team we have to decide which platform we're going to stick with regarding to bitcoin.

Comment: This is a shameless plug, but I wrote this library for Bitcoin you might want to check out: http://cryptoassetscore.readthedocs.org/ - It's based on my experiences working in a Bitcoin exchange. The library does a lot of things "right" like accounting and transactions and e.g. make race condition based issues and attacks impossible.

Comment: It's very secure. If you are a payment processor company I'd suggest you to read through at least this page: http://cryptoassetscore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integrity.html

Comment: Also big Bitcoin exchanges (LocalBitcoins, Bitstamp) use Python

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib) which is used by many exchanges, payment processors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

API selection with other technology selection is having major dependencies on final goal. so you have to select the best suit of technology as per the business requirement.

Comment: Upvoted, because it's true. However I won't mark it as "best answer", because it is incomplete. In order to "to select the best suit of technology as per the business requirement" one needs a proper comparison on the opportunities the bitcoin frameworks of the two languages provide to make an educated decision.